# Adding the Apple ProRaW profile to Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, raw, apple

I have Adobe Photoshop Lightroom Classic CC 8.2.1 with Camera Raw 11.2.1.
How do I add the Apple ProRaW profile to it?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment Lightroom do not support RAW files from APPLE. You can check [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html) for reference. Also to open at all these DNG files you need CameraRAW 15

So you should wait for Adobe to release appropriate version (and update Lightroom)